# Laravel5.8 update image. Call to a member function store() on null

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-5, upload

I am creating profile edit function in my laravel project.

I want to update profile image. When I upload a new image, I can see a new image in profile/index.blade.php.

But when I didn't upload an image, I could not see any image in profile/index.blade.php. And I got an error which says

> Call to a member function store() on null
>   [image]

Profile edit page is profile/create.blade.php. And when I hit save button, I can redirect to a profile page, profile/index.blade.php.

What I want to accomplish is,

> when I upload a new image, I want to show a new profile on
>   index.blade.php. And if I don't upload an image, I want to redirect to
>   index.blade.php and show a previous profile image.

I have profile folder in my Storage. I have already done php artisan storage:link.

index.blade.php

```
<div class="person">
                    @if(empty(Auth::user()->profile->image))
                    <img src="{{asset('image/image1.jpg')}}" >
                    @else

                    <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.Auth::user()->profile->image) }}" >

                    @endif
                </div>
```

create.blade.php

```
    <div class="content">
    <div class="userinfo">
        <div class="profile">
        </div>
        <div class="image-preview" id="imagePreview">
            @if(empty(Auth::user()->profile->image))
            <img src="{{asset('image/image1.jpg')}}" id="image-preview__image">
            @else
            <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.Auth::user()->profile->image) }}"  id="preview">
            @endif
    </div>

    <form action="{{ route('profile.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="image">
            @csrf
    <div class="preview">
            <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
        <label for="file">
            Change Image
        </label>
    </div>
    <ul class="information">
        <li>Gender :<br>
            <div class="gender">
                <select name="gender" id="" name="gender" >
                    <option class="option" value="@if(empty(Auth::user()->profile->gender))Select Gender
                            @else{{ Auth::user()->profile->gender }}@endif" selected="selected">
                            @if(empty(Auth::user()->profile->gender))Select Gender
                            @else{{ Auth::user()->profile->gender }}@endif
                    </option>
                    <option value="male" >male</option> 
                    <option value="female" class="selected">female</option> 
                    <option value="any">any</option> 
                </select>       
            </div>
        </li>   
        <li>Country :<br>
            <div class="country">
                <select name="country" id="" name="country">
                        <option class="option" value="@if(empty(Auth::user()->profile->country))Select country
                                @else{{ Auth::user()->profile->country }}@endif" selected="selected">

                                @if(empty(Auth::user()->profile->country))Select country
                                @else{{ Auth::user()->profile->country }}@endif
                        </option>
                        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option> 
                        <option value="Albania">Albania</option> 
                        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option> 
                        <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option> 

                </select>
            </div>    
        </li><br>
        <li>Birthday :<br>
            <input type="text" class="birthday" id="bod" name="bod" 
            value="@if(!empty(Auth::user()->profile->bod)){{ Auth::user()->profile->bod }}@endif">
        </li>
        <li> Instagram :<br>
        <input type="text" class="instagram"  name="instagram" 
            value="@if(!empty(Auth::user()->profile->instagram)){{ Auth::user()->profile->instagram }}@endif">
        </li><br>
        <li>User Description :<br>
            <textarea name="description" id="" cols="60" rows="10">@if(!empty(Auth::user()->profile->description)){{ Auth::user()->profile->description }}@endif</textarea></li>
            <button type="submit" class="saveBtn">Save</button>
    </ul>

</div>
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\Profile\CreateProfileRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Profile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() 
   {
        $this->middleware('user');
   }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Auth::user()->favourites;
        return view('profile.index')->with('profile', Profile::all())->with('posts', $posts);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('profile.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request, Profile $profile)
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        $data = $request->only(['image']);

        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            //upload it
            $image = $request->image->store('profile');

            //delete old image
            Storage::delete($profile->image);
        } else {
            $image = $profile->image;
        }

        Profile::updateOrCreate(
            ['user_id' => $user_id],
            [   
                'image' => $image,
                'gender' => request('gender'),
                'country' => request('country'),
                'bod' => request('bod'),
                'instagram' => request('instagram'),
                'description' => request('description'),
            ]);

        //flash message

        //redirect user
        return redirect()->route('profile.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Profile $profile)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: If there is no image, how can you save/store that?

Answer (score 1):

Take the image from the profile if no image is uploaded
The issue here is that the injected `$profile` in the `store()` method is not the right one, load it from the user directly.

```php
public function store(Request $request, $id = null)
{
    $profile = auth()->user()->profile;

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        //upload it
        $image = $request->image->store('profile');

        //delete old image
        if ($profile) {
            Storage::delete($profile->image);
        }
    } else {
        $image = $profile->image??null;
    }

    $profile->update(
        [
            'image' => $image,
            'gender' => request('gender'),
            'country' => request('country'),
            'bod' => request('bod'),
            'instagram' => request('instagram'),
            'description' => request('description'),
        ]);

    //flash message

    //redirect user
    return redirect()->route('profile.index');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep my previous image after I redirect to index.blade.php. According to you code, a previous image's gone, and I can see a default image(image1.jpg) but previous one.

Comment: @YoheiUmezu if there is no upload, the previous image will not be removed.

Comment: After I hit the save button without uploading a new image, there is no image anymore in sql database (null).

Comment: @YoheiUmezu then there was no image to start with in `$profile`

Comment: Do you mean I need to set a default image in Storage/profile folder ? Because my image1.jpeg is outside of profile folder.

Comment: @YoheiUmezu If there is **no image** in the profile and **no image is uploaded**, what do you expect the image to be ?

Comment: For example, if a user wants to edit only a name field, user does not upload a new image, and hit save button after he finishes name field right ? In such a case, I want show user’s image which is uploaded in previous time in index.blade.php.

Comment: @YoheiUmezu ok, that suppose that the upload was done at least one time, but what happens if no upload has occurred ? in all cases, the code above preserve the value of `$profile->image` in all cases. but if there is no image, it will preserve the `null`

Comment: I have image1.jpeg as a default image in a folder called “image”. The path is public/image. So even if I don’t upload any images, apparently, the image field is never empty.

Comment: @YoheiUmezu so were is the issue with my answer ?

Comment: I could upload an image. And again, I went to create.blade.php to edit profile, and hit save button without uploading a new image. Then I redirected back to index.blade.php, but I couldn’t see a previous profile image but image1.jpeg(default image).

Comment: @YoheiUmezu cab you add to your question the whole new code for the `store()` method?

Comment: I changed form part in create.blade.php by  <form action="{{ isset($profile) ? route('profile.update', $profile->id) : route('profile.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf and  followed your answer but it didn't work,,,

Comment: But if I use profile.store, I cannot use your answer. Public function update ~.

Comment: Alright, thank you. But I got this error Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\UserController::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected......

Comment: @YoheiUmezu put a default value to $id